# Python Homework - sum of perfect squares

Tags: python

I need help with a python homework question.

"Assume there is a variable , h already associated with a positive integer value. Write the code necessary to compute the sum of the perfect squares whose value is less than h, starting with 1. (A perfect square is an integer like 9, 16, 25, 36 that is equal to the square of another integer (in this case 3*3, 4*4, 5*5, 6*6 respectively).) Associate the sum you compute with the variable  q. For example, if h is 19, you would assign 30 to q because the perfect squares (starting with 1) that are less than h are: 1, 4, 9, 16 and 30==1+4+9+16."

So far I get really close to having it right but it always does one extra number than it needs. For example with putting in 19, instead of stopping at 1,4,9,16 it adds 25 too.

heres my code so far

```
h_i=input()
h=int(h_i)
s=0
q=0
total=s**2
while total<=h:
     s+=1
     total=s**2
     q+=total
     print(total)
print(q)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `s+=1` and `total=s**2` at the end of your loop, so that the condition (which I believe should be `total<h`) is checked *before* it's added to `q`.

```
h_i=input()
h=int(h_i)
s=0
q=0
total=s**2
while total<h:
     q+=total
     print(total)
     s+=1
     total=s**2
print(q)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to suggest a different approach to this using a more "Pythonic" way with list comprehension:

```
>>> highest = 19 # in your case this is h
lst = list (n**2 for n in range(1, highest + 1))
lst
[1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> print '\n'.join(str(p) for p in lst)
1
4
9
16
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest modifying your code to improve readability and spacing. Additionally, you can start counting at 1 (i = 1) since you state a positive integer must be given.

```
h = int(input('insert positive integer: '))
i = 1
total = 0

while total <= h:
    total += i ** 2
    i += 1

print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

And now... for something *completely* different:

```
h = int(input())
n = int((h - 1) ** 0.5)
q = n * (n + 1) * (2*n + 1) // 6
print(q)
```

Comment: That's the mathematician's version ;-). Btw. there is `sqrt()` in python. Any may be not everybody learns that `n * (n + 1) * (2*n + 1) // 6` is the sum of all squares up to `n` at school. So, a little explanation would have been useful.

Answer (score 0):

What you care about is that the current value of `n**2` is less than `h`. So make sure you test that value.

```
h = 19
n = 1
q = 0

while n**2 <= h:
    q += n**2
    n += 1

print("Sum of squares less than {} is: {}".format(h, q))
```

Answer (score -1):

while I love simplicity, here is my take and I have tested in the lab, it works:

```
q=0
n=0
while n*n<h:
q+=n*n
n+=1
```